# In town but not in the town

Tags: prepositions, determiners

We say "the best restaurant in town" but not "what is the best restaurant in the town". Why is this?

Comment: best rastaurant in the town seems fine to me. It is just less common. I have seen proper uses of it though. I would guess it is informal.

Comment: You can say either, but they mean different things, compare at *in school* vs *in the school* (or *at school* vs *at the school*), likewise *at home* vs *at the home*, *in bed* vs *in the bed*, and so on with *jail*, *sea*, *work*, and many others.

Comment: Conversely, "best restaurant in *the* city" is the correct idiom for a city.  Weird, huh?

Answer (score 3):

It's an idiomatic usage.  The proof is that you can say "the best restaurant in town" whether you're talking about a major city, a country town or a **wide spot in the road** (another idiom, of course).

Comment: Your proof is invalid. The word town by itself can mean a major city, a country town or a wide place in the road.

Comment: And that's why it's absolutely valid. I said it was an idiom.  Calling Chicago, for example, "my kind of town" is idiomatic, because Chicago is a major city, not a town.

Comment: I mean "town" can't be an idiom because it is only one word. It may be an idiomatic usage in the sense that it's a usage that would come naturally to a native speaker, but saying so doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score -4):

Isn't this the same as an American that says something is "in back of the car" instead of "in the back of the car"? Just development of the English language due to laziness.

Comment: "In back of the car" means behind the car, outside of it.  "In the back of the car" means in the trunk or rear seat.  Not laziness at all.